# Abrir galeria [CORDOVA]

Tags: apache-cordova, cordova-plugin, galeria

Eu tenho um app webview de um site meu. Neste site tem uma aba de upload de imagens, eu preciso que meu app abra a galera do meu celular, porém, ele não abre de jeito nenhum. Já tentei instalar uns plugins mas também não deu. Alguém, já passou por isso? 
Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

creio que este plugin seja o que você está procurando:
https://github.com/jverlee/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-camera

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Viniciius, eu tirei apenas o accept = ".jpg, .jpeg" da tag input file e funcionou. Eu passei uma longas horas atrás de solução de uma coisa simples. Mas muito obrigado!